# Is it possible to craft a glob that matches files in the current directory and all subdirectories?

Tags: shell, glob

For this directory structure:

```
.
|-- README.txt
|-- firstlevel.rb
`-- lib
    |-- models
    |   |-- foo
    |   |   `-- fourthlevel.rb
    |   `-- thirdlevel.rb
    `-- secondlevel.rb

3 directories, 5 files
```

The glob would match:

```
firstlevel.rb 
lib/secondlevel.rb 
lib/models/thirdlevel.rb
lib/models/foo/fourthlevel.rb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies if I've missed the real point of the question but, if I was using sh/bash/etc., then I would probably use *find* to do the job:

```
find . -name '*.rb' -type f
```

Globs can get a bit nasty when used from within a script and *find* is much more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, `**/*.rb` works

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby itself:

```
Dir.glob('**/*.rb') perhaps?
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can't be done from `bash`

If you using `zsh` then

```
ls **/*.rb
```

will produce the correct result.

Otherwise you can hijack the `ruby` interpreter (and probably those of other languages)

```
ruby -e "puts Dir.glob('**/*.rb')"
```

Thanks to Chris and Gaius for your answers.